# Easy way to get day number of current quarter?

Tags: php, date, date-arithmetic

PHP provides ways to get the number of the current day of the month (date('j')) as well as the number of the current day of the year (date('z')). Is there a way to get the number of the current day of the current quarter?

So right now, August 5, it is day 36 of the third quarter.

If there is no standard way of calculating this, does anyone have a (prefereably PHP-based) algorithm handy?

Comment: How are you defining "quarter"?

Comment: A group of three months.

Comment: Pseudocode: day_of_quarter(y, m, d) = day_of_year(y, m, d) - day_of_year(y, 3*((m-1) % 3) + 1, 1) + 1

Comment: (assuming all values are 1-based)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I wrote a class with the following methods. Enjoy.

```
public static function getQuarterByMonth($monthNumber) {
  return floor(($monthNumber - 1) / 3) + 1;
}

public static function getQuarterDay($monthNumber, $dayNumber, $yearNumber) {
  $quarterDayNumber = 0;
  $dayCountByMonth = array();

  $startMonthNumber = ((self::getQuarterByMonth($monthNumber) - 1) * 3) + 1;

  // Calculate the number of days in each month.
  for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) {
    $dayCountByMonth[$i] = date("t", strtotime($yearNumber . "-" . $i . "-01"));
  }

  for ($i=$startMonthNumber; $i<=$monthNumber-1; $i++) {
    $quarterDayNumber += $dayCountByMonth[$i];
  }

  $quarterDayNumber += $dayNumber;

  return $quarterDayNumber;
}

public static function getCurrentQuarterDay() {
  return self::getQuarterDay(date('n'), date('j'), date('Y'));
}
```

Answer (score 81):

How about:

```
$curMonth = date("m", time());
$curQuarter = ceil($curMonth/3);
```

Comment: I really can't figure out why this answer has received so many upvotes as it is not answering the question at all - it's merely finding the quarter which was not the question

Comment: It's getting upvotes because people come here while looking for a mathematical formula to find out the quarter

Comment: For those looking zero indexed quarter: just use floor instead of ceil. (tested)

Comment: $curMonth = date("m", time());

$curQuarter = (int)ceil($curMonth / 3);

Answer (score 12):

```
function date_quarter()
{
    return ceil(date('n', time()) / 3);
}
```

or

```
function date_quarter()
{
    $month = date('n');

    if ($month <= 3) return 1;
    if ($month <= 6) return 2;
    if ($month <= 9) return 3;

    return 4;
}
```

Comment: its been 5 years and all, but.. this returns the quarter, not the day in the quarter

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/) it has easy modifiers for getFirstOf{Month,Year,Quarter}()

```
<?php
//take current date
$now = Carbon\Carbon::now();

//modify a copy of it to the first day of the current quarter
$firstOfQuarter = $now->copy()->firstOfQuarter();

//calculate the difference in days and add 1 to correct the index
$dayOfQuarter = $now->diffInDays($firstOfQuarter) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean a calendar-quarter (because a company fiscal year can start in any month of the year), you could rely on the date('z') to determine the day-of-year, and then keep a simple array of the day each quarter starts on:

```
$quarterStartDays = array( 1 /* Jan 1 */, 90 /* Mar 1, non leap-year */, ... );
```

Then with the current day-of-year you can first locate the largest start-day that's less than or equal to the day-of-year, then subtract.

Note that you need different numbers depending on the leap year.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
function day_of_quarter($ts=null) {
    if( is_null($ts) ) $ts=time();
    $d=date('d', $ts);
    $m=date('m', $ts)-1;
    while($m%3!=0) {
        $lastmonth=mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, date("d", $ts),   date("Y",$ts));
        $d += date('t', $lastmonth);
        $m--;
    }
    return $d;
}
echo day_of_quarter(mktime(0, 0, 0, 1, 1,2009));
echo "\n";
echo day_of_quarter(time());
echo "\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function quarter_day($time = "") {

    $time = $time ? strtotime($time) : time();
    $date = intval(date("j", $time));
    $month = intval(date("n", $time));
    $year = intval(date("Y", $time));

    // get selected quarter as number between 1 and 4
    $quarter = ceil($month / 3);

    // get first month of current quarter as number between 1 and 12
    $fmonth = $quarter + (($quarter - 1) * 2);

    // map days in a year by month
    $map = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31];

    // check if year is leap
    if (((($year % 4) == 0) && ((($year % 100) != 0) || (($year % 400) == 0)))) $map[1] = 29;

    // get total number of days in selected quarter, by summing the relative portion of $map array
    $total = array_sum(array_slice($map, ($fmonth - 1), 3));

    // get number of days passed in selected quarter, by summing the relative portion of $map array
    $map[$month-1] = $date;
    $day = array_sum(array_slice($map, ($fmonth - 1), ($month - $fmonth + 1)));

    return "Day $day on $total of quarter $quarter, $year.";

}

print(quarter_day("2017-01-01")) . "\n"; // prints Day 1 on 90 of quarter 1, 2017.
print(quarter_day("2017-04-01")) . "\n"; // prints Day 1 on 91 of quarter 2, 2017.
print(quarter_day("2017-08-15")) . "\n"; // prints Day 46 on 92 of quarter 3, 2017.
print(quarter_day("2017-12-31")) . "\n"; // prints Day 92 on 92 of quarter 4, 2017.
```

Comment: You should provide some example input and output, as well as an explanation of your code, rather than just dumping the raw source.

Comment: Thank you, the code was pretty much self explaining, but here you go.

Answer (score 0):

We need to calculate the date of the first quarter first

```
$current_month = date('m');

// Get first month of quarter
$new_month = (3 * floor(($current_month - 1 ) / 3)) + 1;

// Add prefix zero if needed
$new_month = substr('0' . $new_month, -2);

$first_quarter_day_date = date('Y') . '-' . $new_month . '-01';
```

next we calculate the http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime($first_quarter_day_date);
$datetime2 = new DateTime();

$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%a days');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that this thread went a bit beyond the question, and it's the first response to many google searches with "Quarter" & "PHP" in them.

If you're working with the ISO standards of organization, which you should if you're doing a business app, then

```
$curMonth = date("m", time());
$curQuarter = ceil($curMonth/3);
```

Is NOT correct, because the first day of a year in the ISO standards, can be 30, or 31 December.

Instead, you should use this :

```
  $current_yearly_cycle_year_number = 2019;
  $current_yearly_cycle_start->setISODate( $current_yearly_cycle_year_number, 1, 1 );
  $current_yearly_cycle_end->setISODate( $current_yearly_cycle_year_number, 53, 1 );

  if( $current_yearly_cycle_end->format("W") !== "53" )
    $current_yearly_cycle_end->setISODate( $current_yearly_cycle_year_number, 52, 1 );

  $week_number_start = intval( $current_yearly_cycle_start->format( "W" ) );
  $timestamp_start_quarter = ( $week_number_start === 1 ? 1 : intval( ceil( $current_yearly_cycle_start->format( "m" ) / 3 ) ) );

  var_dump( $timestamp_start_quarter );
```