# PHP week to quarter (date)

Tags: php, date, format

i store a date information as **week** into my SQL database table as a varchar. Example: 2022-W10
I want to have the **quarter** out of this week. Which is in my example Quarter 1 Year 2022. Is there any possibility in PHP? I have not found anything on the PHP date() documentation for this.

Comment: Should the first day of the week determine the quarter? Keep in mind that some weeks might start in one quarter and end in another.

Comment: True this can happen. I guess the first day makes sense. Thank you for this hint.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert week number and year into unix timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763340/how-to-convert-week-number-and-year-into-unix-timestamp)

Comment: Once you have the date, [deducing the quarter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1234443/easy-way-to-get-day-number-of-current-quarter) should be immediate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A date object can be created directly from a string such as '2022-W10' and the month can be determined using the format method. The calculation of the quarter is then just some school math.

```
$dateFromDb = '2022-W10';

$month = date_create($dateFromDb)->format('n');
$quarter = (int)(($month+2)/3);  //int(1)
```

If the year is also required, this solution is available:

```
$dateFromDb = '2022-W49';

$dateTime = date_create($dateFromDb);
$quarter = (int)(($dateTime->format('n')+2)/3);

echo 'Quarter '.$quarter.' Year '.$dateTime->format('Y');
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean this problem can be solved by next steps:

```
<?php
$date = '2022-W10';

// 1. parce year & week from string
preg_match('/(\d{4})-W(\d+)/', $date, $matches);
$year = $matches[1];
$week_no = $matches[2];
printf('Year: %d, Week no.: %d' . PHP_EOL, $year, $week_no);

// 2. create date by year & week number
$week_start = new DateTime();
$week_start->setISODate($year, $week_no);

// 3. get month number from date
$month = $week_start->format('n');
printf('Month: %d' . PHP_EOL, $month);

// 4. get quarter
$quarter = ceil($month/3);

printf('Quarter: %d' . PHP_EOL, $quarter);
```

[Test PHP date conversion online](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php8/cbe57956342558cc2087e42234163746/)